# How to pass HttpSession object from server side to Client side through API in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I am working on spring boot application where I need to get the HTTP Session from redis cache and pass it to client side.

So, here I am getting Http Session from the redis cache by session Id.

**Dto class -**

```
 public class UserTokenResponse extends BaseDTO implements Serializable {
    private HttpSession currentSession;
    }
```

**In service method -**

```
UserTokenResponse userTokenRespDTO =  new UserTokenResponse();
    HttpSession session = httpSessionFactory.getObject();
          if(session.getAttribute(sessionId) != null){
                   userTokenRespDTO.setCurrentSession(session);
           }
```

**In controller -**

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
UserTokenResponse userTokenRespDTO = new UserTokenResponse ();
responseHeaders.set("SESSION_ID",userTokenRespDTO.getCurrentSession().toString());
return ResponseEntity.ok()
       .headers(responseHeaders)
       .body(userTokenRespDTO);
```

So If I execute this and see the result in postman and I can see there is a header called SESSION_ID but value seems like not the session object.

[image]

So I want to pass session object. Is this correct?

Thanks,
Dasun.

Comment: Are you sure you *want* to do that? That's a massive violation of encapsulation and basically boils down to dumping your entire back end state on the client. Why not figure out the specific data the UI actually needs and send that?

Comment: @NickBailey Thanks for the reply. I checked with my lead, He is telling that session object is not returning to the UI but to another service. If So is this correct?

Comment: It still seems a bit odd, but then, server side sessions for anything other than auth state seems odd to me since I am used to stateless services.